# AngularJS watch an object as a whole not each property independent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object that looks like this:

```
messages = {
prop1: "text1",
prop2: "text2",
prop3: "text3"
}
```

I use the properties in different places in my html template like

```
<span>{{messages.prop1}}</span>
<div>{{messages.prop2}}</div>
```

The problem is that when I check $rootScope.$$watchers I see a watch for every property. Is there a way to have angular only watch for the entire object and not each property individual?

Comment: How is that a problem? Why would angular care if you change something else in the object?

Comment: check this to unbind after first load https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

Comment: @JonathandeM. I already looked at it, but the problem is that the entire object can change so I need the 2 way data binding. My only concern is that I don't want angular loop through 100 properties when it can only check if the object changed or not.

Comment: It probably better to compare properties instead of compare object as a whole in $watch. because if you just the property of an object, `===` comparison will be `true`, and angular will think the object is not changed.

Comment: So you're trying to fix a non-existent yet performance problem by applying a fix that you think will improve things, although it won't. Watching the object will trigger a change every time any other, unrelated property is modified. And angular would have to compare every unrelated property, recursively, instead of just comparing the ones that need to be compared. Don't pre-optimize: it's the root of all evil. And trust the Google engineers: they know what they're doing.

Comment: @JBNizet You are probably right, it may not be a performance problem even tho in my beginner's opinion it sure looks like it. Every time angular start the digest cycle it checks all the watchable "objects" + dirty checking. From my understanding after reading "
Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS" digest cycle goes through all the watchable components no matter which gets changed (or what events gets triggered) because any change on a component can trigger a change to a totally different one and angular needs to check if that happened (the reason of dirty checking).

Comment: Yes, but is it faster to iterate through 2 string properties of one object, or to iterate through one object, and then iterate over the 10 properties it contains, recursively?

Comment: No, but I was thinking it was faster to objOld === objNew (not sure if this world work). But you are probably right, I may be trying to improve performance where it is not the case.

Comment: Using that would only trigger the change if the object is replaced by another one, and not when the property changes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to initiate a deep watch, you need to pass `true` in the third argument. This will accomplish what you are looking for:

```
$scope.$watch('messages', function(newVal, oldVal){...}, true);
```

For more information [read the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch).

Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/mSw5uxhZSl3sULh6migf?p=preview

Comment: This is not what OP's question is about.

Comment: @Stewie, I feel it answers the question as it is written but after reading the OPs comments, I feel he meant to ask something else. Having said that, I am going to leave this answer in case someone else stumbles upon it.